# Groups and queues and stacks

Tags: sequences-and-series, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

As I review my elementary CS material to prepare for an interview I cannot help but think that I missed a key connection when studying this prior: I think I missed the relationship between operations on a countable sequence and certain kinds of groups. The problem is I am having trouble spitting it out.

Take the most basic examples, FIFO and LIFO (first-in-first-out, or  a queue, vs last-in-first-out, or a stack). FIFO is trivially "isomorphic" to LILO I believe because of symmetry (your last is my first), and the same can be said for FILO.

What can we say about the relationship between FIFO and LIFO? They are clearly "different" structurally, and I want to give them a group-theoretic structure, but I'm having trouble picking a group.

My best (stupid) idea so far is to take an arbitrarily-long sequence, wrap it around (glue the "first" and "last" element, call it 0), and then deal with operations around the loop.

So...

- The identity is doing nothing
- The operation is composition
- The members are finitely-generated by one (or more) elements: push at least.
- Order of push is the order of the group (unfortunately makes it impossible to deal with unbounded-sized groups, I think.)
- Pop is another element, and pop can be either the inverse of push (as in LIFO) or (something else in the other case?)

Is this close? How can you generalize thoughts about queues and stacks and other data structures with respect to group theory?